# One adj. word for "have never been used before"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am programmer and want to say "The programming language I have never used before" in very short word like "... programming language"
What could that be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few alternatives involving prepositions:

> I am *unfamiliar with / illiterate in / ignorant of / incognizant of / inconversant with* this programming language.

As mentioned, *unfamiliar* can also be used directly as an adjective applying to the programming language. The "to me" is then implicit in the meaning.

Answer (score 6):

**unfamiliar** - This is an [unfamiliar](http://thefreedictionary.com/unfamiliar) programming language to me.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply say: "I am inexperienced with this programming language".

Answer (score 2):

You could try

> I am a *novice/neophyte/newbie/virgin* in this programming language.

If you wished to indicate that you were not experienced, but dedicated to learning the language, you might say

> I am an *acolyte/apprentice* in this programming language.

[Note: Before I am inundated by the Slash Police, I am not advocating the use of "/" in actual sentences, but merely suggesting a choice.]

Comment: "virgin" definitely sounds weird when applied to a programming language...

Comment: @Noldorin - I have neve heard it used as such, but the term is getting more widespread usage, e.g., the popular cable show on HGTV in the US called "Property Virgins", i.e. first time home buyers.

Comment: Yeah, I believe you. I think it's less popular in Britain still, as it's sexual connotations are still very strong. It is sometimes used jokingly to describe a first-time experience with something though.

Comment: virgin noun
MW’s second definition:
1b : a person who is inexperienced in a usually specified sphere of activity

Answer (score 2):

> What could that be?

"I have not used X before."